# Can't seem to put brackets around a join result in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using checkbox values to fill an array and then joining those elements I need to put brackets around the joined element to carry out a google place type request.

These are the checkboxes:

```
<form id= "checkboxes">
<label> Types of Places</label>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/style.css">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="woodland" class="places"/>
    <label for="woodland"><img src="../img/Woodland.jpg" /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="lodging" class="places"/>
    <label for="viewpoint"><img src="../img/Viewpoint.jpg" /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="restaurant" class="places"/>
    <label for="restaurant"><img src="../img/Restaurant.jpg" /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="museum" class="places" />
    <label for="historical"><img src="../img/Historical.jpg" /></label>
  </form>  

</form>
```

This is the code for getting the checkbox values into the array:

```
$(".places").change(function()
    {
        placeT = [];
        $(".places").each(function()
        {
            if( $(this).is(':checked') )
            {
                placeT.push($(this).val());
            }
        });
        alert( placeT );
    });
```

This is the JavaScript for joining the elements and performing the place search:

```
function findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex) {

   var typeP = placeT.join('", "');

   var request = {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
       types: typeP
   };

   //alert(request.bounds);
   service.radarSearch(request, function (results, status) {
   if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
     alert("Request["+searchIndex+"] failed: "+status);

   }
   // alert(results.length);
   document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += "bounds["+searchIndex+"] returns "+results.length+" results<br>"
   for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
     var marker = createMarker(result);
   }
   searchIndex++;
   if (searchIndex < boxes.length) 
     findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex);
   });
}
```

The final format for the `types` in the request needs to be ["museum", "restaurant"] for example. The search works fine as `types: ["museum", "restaurant"]` but I can't seem to place brackets around the `typeP` result. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want your place array as json string? If yes Use JSON.stringify() it will give you json for your array.

Comment: you are missing the outer quotes: `var typeP = '"'+placeT.join('", "')+'"';` And do need brakets around it?

Comment: Just pass the array like: var request = {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
       types: placeT
   }; without using the join().

Comment: @Alok That fixed it, thanks!

Comment: glad it helped, can you please upvote my annswer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the array like: var request = { bounds: boxes[searchIndex], types: placeT }; without using the join()